# Are there open source software that let OS X see a generic NAS as a Time Machine destination?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, nas, open-source

Is it possible to use "Time-Machine" with an external hard-drive through an IP?

I have an external HD connected to a Raspberry Pi and I have installed SSH. What I am hoping to achieve is this:

I have a Mac Mini and a Macbook Pro, I want their back-ups to be in-sync but, through the user of an IP that is directed to the raspberry pi that connects the hard-drive.  I know/read that this is possible using Airport extreme but, I do not have that, instead a standard router but I am able to port forward.

Can anyone recommend any open source solutions rather than needing a Time Capsule or OS X Server running on the NAS?

Comment: What do you mean by "backups being in sync"? Are you looking for a backup or for a syncing solution? Mixing these two concepts may lead to very bad results...

Comment: @patrix Thanks for the reply. So I could use a back-up for my mac mini but it also backs-up the file on my MBP as well. M main concern is setting time-machine using an IP.. Any ideas? :)

Comment: You need a way to make the drive visible to the Mac (like a conventional NAS). Don't think SSH will help here, you need to run something like NFS on the Pi (and then make sure that OS X accepts the shared drive as a backup destination).

Comment: @patrix network based time machine requires server side software, plain NAS will most likely not work well.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank's for your reply. Could you suggest any tutorials online?

Comment: Look at any tutorial which adds Time Machine capability to a Linux distribution (from a remote Mac).  I have not done this myself.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen To not being a pain, I have found this tutorial: http://garmoncheg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/time-capsule-for-25.html would this be ok to what I am after? Thank you

Comment: Looks interesting but I have no actual experience with what he tries to do.  Note that you must use the same version of Linux as the author to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is Netatalk. It is excellent software, and if run with a zfs backend, it is simply perfect as a time machine target.